# Serenity BDD framework test case fails after Chrome Version update 116

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 . Here is my serenity.conf file code.

```
serenity {
take.screenshots = FOR_FAILURES
}
webdriver {
  driver = chrome
  autodownload = true
}
headless.mode = false
chrome.switches = "--start-maximized;--window-size=1920,1080;--remote-allow-origins=*"
```

Comment: issue here: https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues/3227

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Followed the below steps and resolved the issue. ✅✅✅

- Go to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager
- Get the latest WebDriverManager dependency (I used 5.5.2 and it worked for me)
- Paste the dependency into your pom.xml file.
- Load the Maven changes
- Run your tests.

[image]
[image]